# Flow not picking up newly created directory

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, flowtype, nuclide-editor

I created a new directory `src` with some sub directories in my React Native project, but Flow is not running diagnostics on code files in that directory.

But flow works well on files in root directory for example `index.ios.js`, I tried adding "./src/" manually in the `.flowconfig` under `[include]` as well but nothing seems to work

How can enable full support for `*.js` files under my `src/` directory

Comment: Where is your .flowconfig?
Are you adding the `@flow` annotation in the new files?

Comment: .flowconfig is put in root directory of project....not sure how to use @flow annotation but what I understood from react native and nuclide docs, it should be supported by default

Comment: You need to have a comment at the top of each file you want to check with `@flow` in it. Otherwise Flow will not check those files.

Comment: is there anything else we need to do, asking as I did try adding //@Flow in the beginning of every js file but its doesnt seem to work as it works for index.ios.js